# Does the leader connect to a ordinary node?

Tags: network

Does the leader connect to an ordinary node? I noticed that the leader use turbine to collect or send out the transactions, so does the leader receive or send out the transactions to a ordinary node?

Answer (score 1):

> Does the leader connect to an ordinary node?

Not sure what you're referring to here by "ordinary node"? Other validators?

> I noticed that the leader use turbine to collect or send out the transactions,

This is slightly incorrect - turbine is the protocol for distributing proposed blocks (ie packed transactions) across the network. The proposed block is broken up into network-sized chunks (called shreds), and the shreds are distributed around. Turbine is NOT part of the aggregation of transactions to leaders.

> so does the leader receive or send out the transactions to a ordinary node?

A leader may receive transactions that could land in a block from many sources with the two most common probably being other validators and RPC nodes.

A leader will send shreds (pieces of proposed blocks) out via turbine. The turbine protocol dictates that while some nodes will receive shreds directly from the leader, other nodes may get the shreds secondhand from other nodes. [This document](https://docs.solana.com/cluster/turbine-block-propagation) gives more detail on the how and why of turbine.

Comment: As I know , the leader prefer to connect to the validators which has more stake sol. So how does the leader pick the validators to connect? What if many validators try to connect to the leader and send invalid transactions?

Comment: The "ordinary node" is the nodes that has not stake any sol or very little sol.

Comment: The common wording for a node that doesn't have any stake is "unstaked node".

For sending transactions to leaders, there are separate "allotments" for staked and unstaked nodes. So while there is more space for staked validators, unstaked nodes (such as RPC nodes) can still get transactions through.

Comment: Also, I see you asked a similar question as your followup below, so I think we can consider the original question answered and I will probably not respond to any other questions in the comments here to avoid duplicate answer.

https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/6329/how-does-the-transactions-send-to-the-leader